# Image fit in thumbnail

Tags: jquery, css, image, thumbnails, blogger

I am having a lot of trouble trying to fit the whole width of my image into the width of the thumbnail. I've tried a various css code and so far none have worked. I am not sure this is better solved withcss or jquery.

For example, if I reduce the width of the thumbs image the image becomes smaller but so does the thumbnail itself and my image is still cut off with large gaps around the thumbnails. All I want is to shrink the image to fit exactly into the max width of the thumbnail. Please help, this problem has had me stumped for over a month.

If it helps, here is a link http://scottribbelobrien.blogspot.ca/

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this css:

```
background-image: url(your-url-here);
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was have the same Issue , until i found something , go to the read more script in the head tag and find this two lines.

```
img_thumb_height = 250;
img_thumb_width = 350;
```

now change the height to this "" , and choose a specific width the image will depending on it you will no more see the image squeezed or expanded.
 this " " tage will adjust the height automatically to fit the Image width.